# How to replace service.jar with dexpreopt enabled

Tags: java, android, service, frameworks

I'm trying to add some log in the TvInputHardwareManager.java and replace the service.jar with the adb tool. After rebooting the machine, I cannot find the log I added. However, I find the root cause. It's the compile option with dexpreopt enabled.

Is there any other way to make it work if not disabled dexpreopt?